# Axios promises returning array of undefined

Tags: node.js, promise, axios, cheerio

I need to wait for a series of axios calls (within a for loop) to complete before processing the data. So I am adding them as an array of promises, then using Promise.all()

```
static myFunction(games) {
  let promises = [];    
  games.forEach(game => {
    promises.push(this.getData(game));
  });

  Promise.all(promises)
    .then(gameData => {
    console.log(" promised:", gameData); //logging as [undefined, undefined, undefined]...
  })
}

static getData(game) {
  return axios({method: "get", url: urlStr})
   .then(res => {
     return parseHTMLData(res);
  }
}

static parseHTMLData(response) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
    const name = $(this).find('.team_name');
    return resolve(name);

  }
}
```

I have confirmed that I get data back successfully in getData(), however within Promise.all() it is coming back as an array of 'undefined' (when I log gameData in the code above).

Any idea why my axios promises are returning undefined?

**Update**: The issue was I was scraping the data retrieved from Axios with Cheerio, and I needed to wrap the Cheerio scraping inside of a Promise.

Comment: @jfriend00 I had simplified the example in my question, but in my actual code I am returning something like {"team" : "Yankees", "city" : "New York"} at the end of getData. I successfully console.log it there. But in Promise.all it shows as undefined for some reason

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Can you make a [mcve] of runnable code please?

Comment: have you tried to catch the error response

Comment: @akolliy yes but there’s no error with the promise - it is delivered the correct amount of objects, but they are undefined

Comment: @vikzilla, How we could reproduce you issue ?

Comment: @nur To reproduce, just follow the code i provided: call a function that returns an axios call within a for loop. The axios call will return a dictionary, which should be expected from the Promise.all() completion array

Comment: @vikzilla, I tried this [code snippet](https://gist.github.com/nurmohammed840/c4aac59b08b45d7af7a7201a6e2a51c0), Everything looks good to me...

Comment: Why does `parseHTMLData` return a promise? Nothing about Cheerio is asynchronous.

Comment: @Bergi Before wrapping it in a promise, it would return undefined.

Comment: @vikzilla I'm pretty certain it would not - unless you forgot to `return name`. Even if cheerio didn't find a `.team_name` element, it would return the cheerio collection object.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vr4oek8s/). This works. maybe there's something wrong with parsing data, and since there is no reject, you get the undefined result.

```
function myFunction(games) {
  let promises = [];    
  games.forEach(game => {
    promises.push(getData(game));
  });
  Promise.all(promises)
    .then(gameData => {
    console.log(" promised:", gameData); //logging as [undefined, undefined, undefined]...
  }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}

function getData(game) {
  return axios({
    method: "post",
    url: "/echo/html/",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"
    },
    data: `html=
<html>
    <body>
    <div class="team">
        <div class="team_name">${game.team_name}</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>`
  })
   .then(res => {
     return parseHTMLData(res);
  });
}

function parseHTMLData(response) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const name = /class="(?:.*?)team_name(?:.*?)"(?:.*?)>(.*?)<\//g.exec(response.data);
    if (name.length > 1)
    {
        return resolve(name[1]);    
    }
    return reject("name not found");
  });
}

let games = [
    { team_name: "TEAM A" },
  { team_name: "TEAM B" },
  { team_name: "TEAM C" }
];

myFunction(games);
```